# How to get keypress value to get the TAB keycode in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dropdown listbox. What is supposed to happen is that after selecting a value in the first dropdown and pressing TAB, the second dropdown should check if the first dropdown really pressed TAB or not.

Here's a rough code idea on this issue.

**HTML**

```
<select id="CarModel">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="CarColor" onchange="TestTab();">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function TestTab(){
 //Check if car model pressed tab before going to CarColor
}
```

Note: There's a possibility of having another field in between the dropdowns (maybe textbox which can show/hide) but the flow still follows that CarColor should know if the previous element pressed the TAB key or did a mouse down.

Comment: You'd have to do the `onchange` on the `CarModel` and set a flag; then on `CarColor` check for that flag.

Comment: Hmm... (1) How is it possible to add a flag during the `onchange` in the `CarModel` when there could be a possibility that there could be a textbox in between those two? (2) How can it be done because the `onchange` cannot detect any keypress there?

Comment: Check my answer.. Something like that should help you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
var Car = {
  modelChangeTabPressed: false,
  modelChange: function() {
    $('#CarModel').keyup(function(e) {
      Car.modelChangeTabPressed = (e.keyCode || e.which) === '9'
    });
  },
  colorChange: function() {
    $('#CarColor').change(function() {
      if (Car.modelChangeTabPressed) {
        //Tab was pressed
      } else {
        //Mouse click or some other way 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Make sure you call the methods to initialize the bindings like this.

```
Car.modelChange();
Car.colorChange();
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `focus` event is fired on the second `<select>` element, you can check the [`relatedTarget` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-FocusEvent-relatedTarget) on the event object in order to determine which element the select menu received focus from.

- In the example below, a `keyup` event is attached to the first `<select>` element in order to determine if the tab key was pressed (which is key 9).
- In the `focus` event listener that is attached to the second `<select>` element, you can check if the `relatedTarget` property refers to the first `<select>` element and then check if the tab key was pressed before the element gained focus.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ncuxja44/)

```
var modelSelect = document.getElementById('CarModel');
var colorSelect = document.getElementById('CarColor');
var previousKeyupEvent = null;

modelSelect.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  previousKeyupEvent = event;
});
colorSelect.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
  var condition = event.relatedTarget === modelSelect &&
                  previousKeyupEvent &&
                  previousKeyupEvent.keyCode === 9;

  if (condition) {
    console.log('Tabbed from #CarColor');
  } else {
    console.log('Did not tab from #CarColor');
  }

  previousKeyupEvent = null; // Reset the variable
});
```

Snippet:

```js
var modelSelect = document.getElementById('CarModel');
var colorSelect = document.getElementById('CarColor');
var previousKeyupEvent = null;

modelSelect.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  previousKeyupEvent = event;
});
colorSelect.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
  var condition = event.relatedTarget === modelSelect &&
                  previousKeyupEvent &&
                  previousKeyupEvent.keyCode === 9;

  if (condition) {
    console.log('Tabbed from #CarColor');
  } else {
    console.log('Did not tab from #CarColor');
  }
  
  previousKeyupEvent = null; // Reset the variable
});
```

```html
<select id="CarModel">
  <option>One</option><option>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="CarColor">
  <option>One</option><option>Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So technically, there's no way for me to get any keypress from the `onchange` event right?